# Codeigniter script Update Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this problem, the controller won't change/updated the data in the database. My table is (***country_wealth***):

**no(primkey) | id_country | year | amount**

My view script for edit:

```
<?php  
      foreach($data->result() as $row){ 
      ?>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/wealth/edit/<?php echo $row->no; ?>" class="btn btn-warning">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</a>
      <?php }
      }
      ?>
    </p>
```

From the script above in my view file will continue to my controller:

```
public function edit()
  {

      $this->load->model('m_login');
      $level = $this->session->userdata('level');
      $area =$this->session->userdata('Amount Edit');
      $data['menu'] = $this->m_login->get_menu_for_level($level);
      $data['title'] = 'Wealth Amount In This Country';
      $data['content'] = 'wealth/v_wealth_edit';

      $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $this->db->from('country_wealth')
               ->where('no',$id);

      $data['data'] = $this->db->get();
      $this->load->view('v_home',$data);
```

After the controller revived the data from my table above, the data will show in my form_edit_file below:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/wealth/update" method="post"  class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return CekForm();">

....
....
<button type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save</button>
```

Then it will go to my controller (Update) after click the Save button:

```
public function update()
  {
    $key['no'] = $this->input->post('no');
    $dt['id_country'] = $this->input->post('id_country');
    $dt['year'] = $this->input->post('year');
    $dt['amount'] = $this->input->post('amount');

    $this->db->update('wealth_country',$dt,$key);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('item_info', 'UPDATE SUCCED.');

      redirect('wealth');
  }
```

It will straight back to my view page, but the problem is "*Nothing happened*" a.k.a failed to updated the data in my table/database (*None of the data in the table was changed*). But there are no errors at all. That's what made me confused. I hope everybody can help me here...

Thank you,

Best regards,

Kris.

***** Note**: *I'm not using model, all my model are in the controller.*

My full script in the controller:

```
public function edit()
      {

          $this->load->model('m_login');
          $level = $this->session->userdata('level');
          $area =$this->session->userdata('Amount Edit');
          $data['menu'] = $this->m_login->get_menu_for_level($level);
          $data['title'] = 'Wealth Amount In This Country';
          $data['content'] = 'wealth/v_wealth_edit';

          $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
          $this->db->from('country_wealth')
                   ->where('no',$id);

          $data['data'] = $this->db->get();
          $this->load->view('v_home',$data);


public function update()
      {
        $key['no'] = $this->input->post('no');
        $dt['id_country'] = $this->input->post('id_country');
        $dt['year'] = $this->input->post('year');
        $dt['amount'] = $this->input->post('amount');

        $this->db->update('wealth_country',$dt,$key);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('item_info', 'UPDATE SUCCED.');

          redirect('wealth');
      }
```

Comment: Try var_dumping all values at your update and set exit() at the end. To be sure that all values are their and they are valid..

Comment: BTW Models are for USING !  Do not setup all your logic inside your controller else you will lose the how idea of MVC..

Comment: Thank you, now I'm using models and it worked. My friend said that if we setup all logic in one controller it will run faster. But sometimes it makes me confused too. Thanks bro.